# How to insert "or" into Microsoft Word search and replace regex

Tags: regex, replace, ms-word

I am trying to find all occurrences of either `<b>` or `</b>` in a document. I'm using wildcards in Microsoft Word search and replace. Here is my search content:

`Find: \<b\>|\</b\>`

My understanding from using regex in Adobe Dreamweaver is the | stands for "or". Is this different in Word? I have referenced [Microsoft's help page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/word-help/find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-advanced-HA102350661.aspx) for info on regex in Word, but I don't see how to insert an "or" into a search.

I note that I have "use wildcards" checked in the search and replace box.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: You will probably get better luck at superuser stackexchange as Stackoverflow is for programming related issues.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize. I will try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know and from the documentation ([this page is a bit more detailed](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm)), there is no way to do that for now.

If there was a way to have 0 or 1 occurrence, you would be able to use something like this in pure PCRE regex as alternative:

```
</?b>
```

But even `{0,1}` doesn't work...

Comment: Maybe if you explain what you are trying to do, there might be a workaround.

Comment: Perhaps my statement in the original is not clear enough. Specifically, I am searching through a Microsoft Word document and am attempting to remove all occurrences of `<b>` and `</b>`. It is easy to just run this as two separate search-and-replace features, but for longer tags (i.e. `<data tag="auto-generated" ref="Bible:Da 12:4">`, I want to be able to have an "or" option so I can write one regex search function and remove/modify multiple erroneous segments of code. P.S. I am inheriting this code, I didn't write the original document, so there is no "Just don't write bad code" option, sadly.

Comment: @1John5vs7 That's much more informative IMO :) By the way, are you removing all html-like tags or just specific tags? To remove all tags, you could use `\<[!>]@\>` where `[!>]@` means any character except `>` repeated as least once.